# AWS CDK: is it possible to create EC2 instance or SG into default VPC without VPC.fromLookup()?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Is it possible to target an EC2 instance or security group at the default VPC, without needing to use [VPC.fromLookup()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-ec2/vpc.html#aws_ec2_Vpc_fromLookup)?

I need to specify the target account at **deploy time**, not synth time, but I can't create either of these 2 resources without either specifying the account & region at synth time, or hardcoding the values into the stack definition.

For example, to create a security group in the default VPC:

```
IVpc vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, "VPC", VpcLookupOptions.builder().isDefault(true).build());

SecurityGroup mySg= new SecurityGroup(this, "MySecurityGroup",
        SecurityGroupProps.builder()
                .vpc(vpc)
                .securityGroupName("my-sg")
                .allowAllOutbound(true)
                .build()
);
```

Is it possible to use CfnParameters here?

Answer (score 1):

Both [InstanceProps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-ec2/instanceprops.html#aws_ec2_InstanceProps_vpc) and [SecurityGroupProps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-ec2/securitygroupprops.html#aws_ec2_SecurityGroupProps_vpc) require an [`IVpc`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.IVpc.html) to be given, and the only way to get that is to either create a VPC or to use [`Vpc.fromLookup()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-ec2/vpc.html#aws_ec2_Vpc_fromLookup) as you pointed out. Neither allow for a `null` value to be given.

My understanding is that even if you were to use [`CfnParameters`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ssm.CfnParameter.html), you would still have to do a lookup to find the VPC that the ID passed in corresponds to (as a VPC ID as a string isn't a `IVpc` resource) using either `Vpc.fromLookup()` or [`Vpc.fromVpcAttributes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-ec2/vpc.html#aws_ec2_Vpc_fromVpcAttributes). It [does seem](https://garbe.io/blog/2019/09/20/hey-cdk-how-to-use-existing-resources/#example-vpc) that the latter does not require accessing your account, but is built for using exported values from another stack not for using parameters, though it may be possible to use for that purpose.